# Can I pass data between 2 input plugin of logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

```
input {
      beats {
       **value** #(geting from the logs)
  }
}
input {
  jdbc {
    statement => "SELECT * from table WHERE ruslit = **value'**"
  }
}
```

*//Pass a value from filebeat logs to jdbc input plugin to assign in the query*

Answer (score 0):

What you need is not a `jdbc` input plugin but the [`jdbc_streaming` filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-jdbc_streaming.html)

```
input {
      beats {
       **value** #(geting from the logs)
  }
}
filter {
  jdbc_streaming {
    statement => "SELECT * from table WHERE ruslit = **value'**"
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the response, can you add more details?

Comment: What kind of details? You'll get logs through your beats input and then you can fetch data from JDBC within the filter based on some value present in your logs. With the level of details of your question, there's not much more I can add here :-)

Comment: The kind of data is logs pulling by Filebeat, there is values I can geting from the logs to assign this values in the query, Let's say the line of logs including value, this value I need to reuse in JDBC statement query.

Comment: That I understood, but you might have to show how such a log line looks like so we can parse it accordingly

Comment: I added the grok filtration to get the value stored in the key for each log line, so how to parse this values in the JDBC query statement?